# How to get the name of type icon set conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet "Bai 1", in range F6:F11,  I have an conditional formatting type icon set 3 arrows. I want to get the name "3 arrows" by VBA. But it's not working.
This is my code:

```
If Worksheets("Bai 1").Range("F6:F11").FormatConditions.Count > 0 Then   
        If Worksheets("Bai 1").Range("F6:F11").FormatConditions(1).Type = 6 Then ' 6 is  xlIconSet
             MsgBox Worksheets("Bai 1").Range("F6:F11").FormatConditions(1).IconSetCondition.IconSet             
    End If    
End If
```

Thanks for your help. Sorry if my English is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`IconSet.ID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.iconset.id) property.

> Returns one of the constants of the `XlIconSet` enumeration, which specifies the name of the icon set used in an icon set conditional formatting rule.

```
MsgBox Worksheets("Bai 1").Range("F6:F11").FormatConditions(1).IconSet.ID
```

and then you can parse the result with a UDF based on the [`XlIconSet` enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xliconset).

```
Private Function GetIconType(ByVal iconID as Long) As String
     Select Case iconID
          Case 1
              GetIconType = "3 Arrows"
          Case 2
              GetIconType = "3 Arrows Gray"
          '... and so on
     End Select
End Function
```